# SQL Server select-where statement issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, between

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise on Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I have a question about tsql in SQL Server 2008. For select-where statement, there are two differnet forms,

(1) select where foo between [some value] and [some other value],

(2) select where foo >= [some value] and foo <= [some other value]? I am not sure whether between-and is always the same as using <= and >= sign?

BTW: whether they are always the same - even for differnet types of data (e.g. compare numeric value, comparing string values), appreciate if anyone could provide some documents to prove whether they are always the same, so that I can learn more from it.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 6):

Yes they are always the same. The [entry in Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922%28SQL.100%29.aspx) for `BETWEEN` says

> BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of
>   test_expression  is greater than or
>   equal to the value of begin_expression
>   and less than or equal to the value of
>   end_expression.

Indeed you can see this easily by looking at the execution plans. You will see that `Between` doesn't even appear in the text. It has been replaced with `>=` and `<=` there is no distinction made between the two.

```
SELECT * FROM master.dbo.spt_values 
WHERE number between 1 and 3 /*Numeric*/

SELECT * FROM master.dbo.spt_values 
WHERE name between 'a' and 'b' /*String*/

select * from sys.objects 
WHERE create_date between GETDATE() and GETDATE()+100 /*Date*/
```

[image]

Comment: How to see execution plans esaily in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio? Sorry, I am new to this topic.

Comment: @Martin Smith, thanks for explaining this. I was just thinking that how can I explain this.

Comment: @George2 - On the "Query" menu select "include Actual Execution Plan" then run the query or `CTRL+M` this shows the actual plan.  Edit: Muhammad has explained how to see the estimated plan. The estimated plan can be better as you don't even have to execute the queries.

Comment: Thanks, besides using query plan, do you have any document to prove they are the same?